# Multithreaded Request With Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, reactjs

**Hello everyone, I am trying to build a ReactJS App which controls and monitors the status of some physical devices. In order to get the status of these physical devices I am using a request that looks like :**

```
axios.get('http://192.168.1.***:8080').then( response => {
    let deviceStatusMode = 0;
    if(response.data.isCritical) {
        deviceStatusMode = 1;
    } else if (response.data.isWarning) {
        deviceStatusMode = 2;
    } else {
        deviceStatusMode = 3;
    }
    let opvObj = {
        "odv1" : deviceStatusMode,
        "odv2" : 2,
        "odv3" : 3
    }
    store.dispatch(odvStatus(opvObj));
});
```

This request need to be sent to several devices (Nearly 9-10). However some of them will be closed, some of them may not answer, so whats the greatest way to avoid waiting this request timeouts and merging them by multithreading approach? Thanks!

Comment: You can define a timeout threshold in the request config and use a catch to do something when it fails. Beyond that not 100% clear what you are looking for. Do you want to know when they have all completed?

Comment: First of all I am glad for your approach and answer, and for your question, Yes.
I want to wait at most 5 seconds for all devices, and after that time I want to collect the results, If some requests are timed out, I will mark them as closed and show that so on the GUI.

Comment: Axios docs show how to configure timeout threshold

Answer (score 1):

For "concurrency" in JS look at using `Promise.all()`.

Check out https://hackernoon.com/concurrency-control-in-promises-with-bluebird-977249520f23 for more info.

Edit the below code as seen necessary but heres a rough outline

```
// assuming these are your devices
const devices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

(async () => {
    // These were then passed to Promise.all() to be executed in parallel. 
    let opvObj = {};
    await Promise.all(devices.map(async (device) => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.1.***:8080')
            .then(response => {
                let deviceStatusMode = 0;
                if (response.data.isCritical) {
                    deviceStatusMode = 1;
                } else if (response.data.isWarning) {
                    deviceStatusMode = 2;
                } else {
                    deviceStatusMode = 3;
                }
                // build up opvObj
                opvObj[`odv${device}`] = deviceStatusMode;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // do something with the error
                console.log(error)
            });
    }));
    //dispatch 
    store.dispatch(odvStatus(opvObj));
})()
```

Comment: Need a `catch` for the ones that timeout or fail

Comment: That is a great approach, thank you. However I think there is one more problem. I have to send these requests to different IPs. Thats why I marked as '*'. So Is it possible to control the Thread-IP-DeviceNumber trio properly?

Comment: @I.K. you would get that from the devices array and access each instance inside `map()`

Comment: @I.K. you could out that info in the `devices` and use the `device` from the map call back to fill in the ip

Answer (score 0):

There is no real concept of multithreading in javascript -- all of the execution takes place on a single thread. However, because javascript has an asynchronous event loop, we can still interoperate different parts of your code without having to wait for any http requests to finish.

Since it looks like you are using redux, all you have to do is keep the same code that you have right now, except you should update the state incrementally (i.e., just 'odv1' instead of 'odv1' - 'odv3' all at once. Take another look at the [redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) docs for how to do that.

Then you can run make several `axios.get` calls right after each other. They won't block each other because of the asynchronous nature of javascript (i.e., the http requests will all be in flight at the same time, not executed strictly sequentially):

```js
axios.get('/dev1').then(...);
axios.get('/dev2').then(...);
axios.get('/dev3').then(...);
axios.get('/dev4').then(...);
axios.get('/dev5').then(...);
```

For more information check out details about the [js event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

If you *really* need to do some operations separate of the main gui thread (i.e., if you have 10,000+ device statuses you need to keep up to date second by second), you can check out [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Based on what you've shared, however, I think this will introduce more complexity than is necessary for your project.

Edit:

One of the above answers proposes `Promise.all`. While I like his method of extracting the core logic into its own function, using `Promise.all` simply combines all of the promises into one. This will still cause you to have to wait until the slowest of your devices responds before you update your store which is almost definitely not what you want. Again, performing incremental updates to the redux store as the http requests return is almost definitely going to be the fastest way to get the most up-to-date information to your user's screen.

Comment: Agreed you could use a combo of both for best results.